# Hyperlink button website

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I need to put button that after click moves user to website. Can someone tell me what should I put into vb and in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Click here to learn about Silverlight" NavigateUri="http://www.silverlight.net" TargetName="_blank" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also in C#

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var task = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask
            {
                URL = "http://siteaddress.com",

            };

            task.Show();
        }
```